# LitElement object property is null

Tags: web-component, lit-element, lit

I have a component which takes an object as a property, but for some reason when rendering `this.item` is undefined.

```
@property({type: Object}) item?: {
    family: {iconUrl: string; name: string};
} | null;

static get styles(): CSSResult[] {
    return [
        css`
            ${unsafeCSS(styles)}
        `
    ];
}

render(): TemplateResult {
    if (this.item) { 
       return html`<div>found item</div>
     } else {
       return html`<div>item not found</div>
     }
}
```

In my HTML I have the following:

```
const item = {  
   family: {
      name: 'title',
      iconUrl: 'url'
   } 

}

html`<my-component item="${item}"></my-component>
```

Is there something I'm missing in order to accept an object as an argument? I've tried adjusting a number of things such as making the arg `.item="{ }"` with no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the property syntax without string quotes:

```
html`<my-component .item=${item}></my-component>`
```

You can tell Lit to not check for the string attribute:

```
@property({attribute: false}) item?: {
    family: {iconUrl: string; name: string};
};
```

You don't need an explicit `null` unless you want to handle it differently from `undefined` (which is the default if you don't set it).

Comment: Ah that does appear to work, however it does not when the object gets passed as a string. `<my-component .item={"iconUrl": "123", "name": "123"}></my-component>`.  I've tried adding type: Object as I believe that is meant to automatically parse the property, but it does not seem to be working.

Comment: @JamesIves No, you'd have to add your own converter, something like `@property({ converter: { fromAttribute: attr => JSON.parse(attr) } })`